# How to save a *.txt file with PHP on a specific path?

Tags: php, fopen, filepath

I am trying to write a simple PHP script that writes a string to .txt file.
Simple. For that I have this:

```
<?php
if(isset(isset($_GET["fileName"]) == true && isset($_GET["output"]) == true){
    $fp = fopen($_GET["fileName"], "a+");
    if($fp !== null){
        fputs($fp, $_GET["output"] . "\r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

But I really need to be able to save to a specific location, so I have written this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["filePath"]) == true && isset($_GET["fileName"]) == true && isset($_GET["output"]) == true){
    $fp = fopen($_GET["filePath"] . $_GET["fileName"], "a+");
    if($fp !== null){
        fputs($fp, $_GET["output"] . "\r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

But of course, this doesn't work.
1. How can I save to a specific location with PHP?
2. Can this path be a relative path? (i just send "/output/" and the save would be done as expected).

Thank you.

Now I am here:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["filePath"]) && isset($_GET["fileName"]) && isset($_GET["output"])){

    $filename=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $_GET['fileName']).'.txt';
    $filepathSanitized='http://thepathtomywebsite/~subdomain/'.$_GET["filePath"].$filename;

    echo $filepathSanitized;  // i get the correct path, but no file is present there 
    $fp = fopen($_GET["filepathSanitized"], "a+");
    if($fp !== null){

        fputs($fp, $_GET["output"] . "\r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else echo ('Something wrong'); // it never gets to this
}
?>
```

And i am calling the above like this:

```
$.get("save_me.php", { filePath: "demo/", fileName: "text", output: 'thing to write into' });
```

But no file is created. I don't know what to debug to find out what goes wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/features.file-upload

Comment: Your nested `isset()` makes no sense and smells like something that would result in a fatal error. Besides that, you really don't need `== true` everytime. That's implied and adding it just bloats your code.

Comment: The nested isset().. Doesn't that help me with checking if something is sent? I thought that is the right way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But no file is created. I don't know what to debug to find out what goes wrong. Thank you.

You should debug the argument that is passed to fopen().

Comment: Thank you for your explicit answer and for your time. I have learned some nice stuff, but the other answer is a little more hands down for the current issue I'm having.

Comment: I understood that i shouldn't allow users to access paths that contain "../" because that could mean that they could browse throughout the entire file tree and possibly replace important files.  Also that it is very important to allow the script to access only the folder that would contain the output files.
I did not use the base_path method because I am working on a server from my school and is has a domain like this "http://students.school.com/~user/XML/" and a base_path echo returns "/servername/studs/user/html/XML" -> this is the filepath from the server, i think.

Comment: Also, I didn't need creating subdirectories, because I only need one folder output, but it's nice to know how to do it.
Thank you again!

Comment: OK, this seems like a solution, but i have 2 issues: 1. $target = realpath(BASE_PATH . $_GET['fileName']); returns nothing. I have updated the base_path with my working string. 2. removed the realpath(), echoed the $target, it seems fine, but no file is created. I am really new to this, sorry for all this trouble.

Comment: Yes, exactly like the above. The file_put_contents(). And added error_reporting(E_ALL); but no error are visible. Sorry..

Comment: Wait.. $.get("save_me.php", { filePath: "demo/", fileName: "text", output: 'thing to write into' });
is still a correct way to call the php right?

Comment: Anyhow, I understand why your method is better, and i will check your answer as the one that helped me the most, because it did. The issue with the file writing is probably something that i don't see right now, but i will fix it. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find this is a permissions issue - debug your code to see if $fp is actually set.

Also, code like this is potentially very dangerous, allowing a file to be created or replaced anywhere the webserver is allowed to access. You should sanitize the fileName, and create the full path yourself, e.g.

```
//clean any nasties from the filename
$filename=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $_GET['fileName']).'.txt';

//calculate a path relative to our document root...
$filepath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/files/'.$filename;
```

Comment: To begin with - thank you, you have raised some very important (it should have been obvious to me though) problems. I will update the status.